# Using std::string.compare() won't work

Tags: c++, compare, stdstring

i have a little problem with the following code:

```
std::string compare = "data_END";
while ((!(temp.compare(compare) == 0)) && std::getline(file, temp)) {
    std::size_t pos = temp.find(' ');
    std::string name = temp.substr(0,pos);
    std::string number = temp.substr(pos);
```

....

So, there is a point when in the file there is a line called "data_END".
it is read correctly as i can see in the debug options. However the .compare() method wont return 0. As i use visual Studio i can also see the details and everything between the strings seems the same exept the capacity. in temp it is 31 and in compare it is 15. Does this make the difference between them? I can't get any further by myself and i would appreciate any help,

thanks guys! :)

Comment: Does `getline()` include the newline?  If so, your sample string doesn't, and the strings won't compare equal, therefore.  You've not shown how `temp` is initialized, either.  Also, the standard way to write `!(temp.compare(compare) == 0)` is `temp.compare(compare) != 0`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, `std::getline` shouldn't. IIRC, `std::istream::getline` does.

Comment: @chris: all of the `getline()` functions strip the newline. There is a string version of `std::istream::get()` which doesn't strip the newline, though.

Comment: @DietmarKühl, Oh, that must be it, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to rewrite this statement:)

```
while ((!(temp.compare(compare) == 0)) && std::getline(file, temp)) {
```

like

```
while ( std::getline(file, temp) && !( temp.compare(compare) == 0) ) {
```

That is at first you have to read a line of the file in string `temp` and only then compare it with string `compare`.

The other problem can be with CR symbol in the text file. That is each line is ended with pair CR ('\r') + LF ('\n'). In this case you should remove it from string temp.

For example you can write

```
while ( std::getline(file, temp) && !( temp.compare(0, compare.size(), compare) == 0) ) {
```

Comment: It would be a nice addition to the answer to explain why changing the order of those two expressions makes a difference.